# Using Svg images from url in react native expo application

Tags: android, react-native, svg, react-native-web, react-native-svg

I have React native expo app that works in WEB, IOS & ANDROID.  I have installed react-native-svg to show svg images from URL. It is working fine with web , but on expo android emulator it showing unknown format.
also using  for loading svg from uri , but it is always undefined.

using code like this.
SvgUri is always unddefined and using Image tag with SVG image uri give error on android

```
import Svg,{SvgUri}  from 'react-native-svg';
<SvgUri
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    uri="http://mydomain/image.svg"
  />
```

Tried to search online, github issues but could not find fix. Any idea what is the correct way to show svg from URI in react native expo app for Android, web and ios

Comment: Share the url to your svg.

Comment: @user18309290  You can use any image with svg url. It is rendering fine in web, but on opening expo app in android , it is showing wrong format type